# Fetch username from user Id and store it in string from firebase firestore in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

The code is simple but I am not getting the output:

[Code Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLNTp.png)

[image: Database Picture]

I tried the below code:

```
final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
Future<String?> getUsername(String userId) async {
  DocumentSnapshot snapshot =
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users').doc(userId).get();

  if (snapshot.exists) {
    Map<String, dynamic> userData = snapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
    String? username = userData['username'];
    print("User name $username");
    return username;
  }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: It helps if you do some local debugging, and show that the code actually should work. For example, `print(userId)` to check if a document with that ID actually exists. If it does, edit your question to show the updated code and its output (so that we too can see that the `userId` matches the document in your screenshot.

Comment: Yeah for debugging process only, I was checking whether I am receiving the userId value in string or not. But its not printing anything in console or not getting stored in string also.

Comment: Please add the `print` statement I said in the code, and `edit` your question (there's a link right under it) and show the updated code and its output. Without that, there's not much more we can do then say that there's likely no document wiht the `userId` value that you're using - which is probably not all that helpful to you.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.